# We can’t connect to the server at precious.htb. HACKTHEBOX

Tags: machine-learning

I cant connect to the server machine named precious.
[Here the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ML94H.png)

I already run the opennvpn.
And gain Lab Accesss

But the IP Address still not working...

Any idea what should i do?

I tried runserver and run the openvpn.
I gained Lab Access too

but when i go to Precious Machine IP Address... it says Server not Found

then i search for this problem on internet, but there is no clue for it

Answer (score 2):

Add IP to the /etc/hosts and it should resolve the issue.

┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~/Downloads]

└─$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost

127.0.1.1       kali

10.10.11.189    precious.htb